# XBMC using a lot of CPU when fullscreen

Tags: compiz, xorg, xbmc

I'm just starting to try out XBMC (from the ubuntu repo) and noticed that it's using a lot of CPU when running fullscreen, even when I'm not playing a movie. There's a definite lag even on the home page with the scrolling footer.

I've toggled the option to use it in windowed mode and it seems to be a lot more responsive. The footer lag seems to be gone.

Does anyone know why this is happening? I would have thought that running fullscreen would have used less resources.

Answer (score 0):

For me, Compiz didn't play well with xbmc at all, that is why I made the following script to start XBMC:

```
#!/bin/bash
metacity --replace &
sleep 2s
xbmc
unity --replace &
exit;
```

It replaces compiz with metacity, and then starts xbmc. When xbmc exits, you get compiz back (there may be some flickering when compiz is restarting)

You can save the script as `xbmc.bash` and make it executable using

```
chmod +x xbmc.bash
```

Then start it! I hope this works for you!