# How do I replace/quit Unity in Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: unity, 13.04, xbmc, metacity

I am trying out Ubuntu 13.04 and the only thing that prevents me from completely switching is XBMC. I am running XBMC from the [wsnipex PPA](https://launchpad.net/~wsnipex/+archive/xbmc-xvba) which is compiled with XVBA support.

XBMC doesn't like Unity that much and if started normally, it is very unresponsive (see also [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/209460/xbmc-using-a-lot-of-cpu-when-fullscreen)) and will not be able to use hardware decoding. A solution in Ubuntu 12.04 is to use the following script to start XBMC:

```
#!/bin/bash
metacity --replace &
sleep 2s
xbmc
unity --replace &
exit;
```

It replaces `unity` by `metacity` and this solves all my problems, however in Ubuntu 13.04 `metacity` is ditched, so I would like to know how I can replace/quit Unity there. (Starting XBMC standalone from the login screen lets me use hardware decoding but it is still a bit unresponsive, much slower than the above script for Ubuntu 12.04)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, it is as easy as installing [metacity [image: Install metacity]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/metacity) from the software center.

The unresponsiveness was caused by *System->Settings->Video Output* where in my case *Vertical blank sync* should be set to *Disabled* (I have a slow machine).

Comment: please can you tick this so that we can take this out of the unanswered queue.  Cheers.